# Honeypot field breaking entire page

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I have a honeypot ('Work Phone') field in a simple contact form. I am hiding (hacking) the element by positioning it fixed and -1000% off the screen.

**The form HTML:**

```
<aside class="enquiry-form">
    <h3 class="heading">Enquire Now</h3>
    <form id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm" action="/products/filtered-water-taps/EnquiryForm" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" name="Name" class="text" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Name" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="email" name="Email" class="email text" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Email" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="text" name="Work Phone" class="text" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Work-Phone" style="position: fixed; left: -1000%;" tabIndex="-1" />
            <input type="text" name="Phone" class="text" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Phone" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Phone" />
            <input type="text" name="Product" value="Filtered Water Taps" class="product" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Product" placeholder="Product" />
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <textarea name="Message" class="textarea" id="EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Message" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Message" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="button dark" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</aside>
```

The problem is, in **ie8** the whole page breaks and I get a white screen, I cannot inspect the element using dev tools which makes debugging very dfficult.

My gut feel is that it has something to do with html5shiv.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this method:

```
#EnquiryForm_EnquiryForm_Work-Phone {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

By the way, I think its better to use a "website" as honeypot field. This is something a spambot allways want's to fill out.

Comment: Ah, good suggestion, I was weighing up at the time which name to use, website seems like a good bet.

I will give the absolute values a go and let you know how I fair,

Comment: That has done the trick! Thanks for the assistance! Answer accepted.